# Equivalent norms on a cartesian product of Hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Notation: $H_0^1=H_0^1(a,b)$, where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.

Let $\|\cdot\|_V$ be a norm on $V:=H_0^1\times H^1_0\times H^1_0$ given by
$$\|(f,g,h)\|_V=\|f'+g+ah\|_{L^2}+\|h'-af\|_{L^2}+\|g'\|_{L^2},$$
where $a$ is a positive constant.

I need help to prove that $(V,\|\cdot\|_V)$ is complete. I have tried to show that $\|\cdot\|_V$ is equivalent to $|\cdot|_V$, where $|\cdot|_V$ is a norm such that $(V,|\cdot|_V)$ is complete, as explained below.

We know that the space $H_0^1$ is complete with the norm $\|f\|_{H^1}=\|f\|_{L^2}+\|f'\|_{L^2}$. Therfore $V$ is complete with the norm
$$\begin{align*}|(f,g,h)|_V&=\|f\|_{H^1}+\|g\|_{H^1}+\|h\|_{H^1}\\
&=\|f\|_{L^2}+\|f'\|_{L^2}+\|g\|_{L^2}+\|g'\|_{L^2}+\|h\|_{L^2}+\|h'\|_{L^2}
\end{align*}$$

By triangular inequality,

$$\|(f,g,h)\|_V\leq\|f'\|_{L^2} + \|g\|_{L^2} + a\|h\|_{L^2} + \|h'\|_{L^2} + a\|f\|_{L^2} + \|g'\|_{L^2}\leq\max\{1,a\}|(f,g,h)|_V$$

So, there exists $c:=\max\{1,a\}>0$ such that $\|(f,g,h)\|_V\leq c|(f,g,h)|_V$ for all $(f,g,h)\in V$.

Now, I need help to show that there exists a constant $d>0$ such that $|(f,g,h)|_V\leq d\|(f,g,h)\|_V$ for all $(f,g,h)\in V$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might not even be true it's equivalent to a norm like that.

My approach would be to show if $(f_n,g_n,h_n)$ is Cauchy in this norm, then $(f'_n + g_n+a h_n)$ , $(h'_n-af_n)$ and $(g'_n)$ converge to some $L^2$ functions, by completeness of $L^2$. Now you should be able to write all 6 of $f_n,g_n,h_n,f'_n,g'_n,h'_n$ in terms of these three to get these converge to some $L^2$ functions, then $(f_n,g_n,h_n)$ converges in the usual norm on that space.

Comment: Do you know how to write $f_n$ in terms of $(f'_n+g_n+ah_n)$, $(h'_n-af_n)$ and $g'_n$? Could you help me?

Comment: Ah it doesn't work how I anticipted (of course, there's 6 functions and 3 "knowns") - I believe you can use Poincare's inequality to deal with all of it. For example, once you know $(g'_n)$ and $(f'_n+g_n+ah_n$ are Cauchy (in $L_2$), you can use poincare to get $\| (f'_n+ah_n)-(f'_m-ah_m) \| \leq \| f'_n + g_n + a h_n \| + C \| g'_n \|$ to deduce $ \| f'_n + a h_n \|$ is Cauchy (In $L^2$).